# SQLPlus - get number of records without aggregate queries

Tags: sql, oracle

This is from a school assignment with the following resctictions:
1. No nested queries
2. No aggregate queries

Essentially I need to get all names that appear 3 or more times in a table.

For example, if my table looks like this:

```
uniqueid |name | some other stuff
-----------------------
0        |Bob  | ...
1        |Bob  | ...
2        |Bob  | ...
3        |Tim  | ...
4        |Tim  | ...
5        |John | ...
6        |John | ...
7        |Bill | ...
8        |Tim  |
```

My desired output is:

```
name
-----
Bob 
Tim
```

This is trivial with aggregate queries:

```
SELECT name
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

But for whatever reason the assignment explicitly prevents me from using (what I perceive to be) the most appropriate tool for the job, and I can't figure out how it could be done.

Comment: Does table have unique key?

Comment: Yes, there is a unique key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No aggregate functions, no analytic functions, no nested queries, works on any Oracle you can probably get. :)

```
select distinct name from tbl 
where level = 3 
connect by prior rowid < rowid and prior name = name and level < 4
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85e8e/19)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function :

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM( SELECT name
           , row_number() over (partition by name order by name ) as RN
      FROM tbl )
      WHERE RN > 2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3fa6/1)

Comment: try it after adding another row with name "tim". you probably meant "rn=3"\

Comment: @beherenow : just adding `distinct ` seems enough.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution that they were looking for was to just brute-force it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.name
FROM table t1, table t2, table t3
WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND
t2.name = t3.name AND
t1.name = t3.name AND
t1.uniqueid <> t2.uniqueid AND
t2.uniqueid <> t3.uniqueid AND
t1.uniqueid <> t3.uniqueid;
```

Comment: The other answers are worth considering.